# How can i use this statement in python?

Tags: python, php, explode

I have this in php and i would like to know how to set up this but in python

```
<?php
  $to_parse = 'palabras,para,separar';
  $array = explode ( ',', $to_parse);
  foreach ( $array as $palabra ) {
  echo $palabra . '>br/<';
  }
?>
```

i had tried this:

```
to_parse = 'palabras,para,separar'
array = list(to_parse)
 
for palabra in palabra:
 print(palabra)
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
to_parse = 'palabras,para,separar'
array = to_parse.split(',')
for palabra in array:
  print("%s >br/<" % palabra)
```